# Android Studio: Images behind other images

Tags: android, layout

What I am trying to do seems very basic in theory, but cannot find any information on this on the web. I have a series of clickable imagebuttons, containing images. I would like it so that when a user clicks on one of these imagebuttons, it becomes highlighted with a simple border.

To achieve this, I have created a basic solid-colour 62x62 pixel image and wish to place it -behind- my original 60x60 imagebutton. This will create the illusion of a border. My plan is to set it to non-visible by default and then have the code set it to visible on click.  Sounds straight-forward.

However, in my layout, the solid-colour image always sits on top of the original image, and I cannot find any way of sending it behind.  I would rather not do this in code, I am sure this is a layout issue (but will set it in code if I absolutely must).

Relevant section of layout, where the ImageView needs to sit behind the player 1 ImageButton:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/Form_PlayerSelection"
    android:background="@drawable/dark_wood">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnPlayer1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/player_blank"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/p1border"
    android:layout_width="62dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:src="@drawable/selectborder"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnPlayer2"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/player_blank"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each child is added in order and to the top of the ViewGroup. So, the bottom element should be your first child.